# Comparing two text files - and save difference to new file

Tags: javascript, save, fs

I'm currently trying to baffle my head through this - so the scenario is:

**1.** Download textFile1 from FTP

**2.** Download textFile2 from FTP

**3.** Read data and compare in textFile1&2 from local files on PC

**4.** Save differences (like full lines) only to textFile 3

I've tried doing fs.readFile on it - and compare fileDiff (npm diff); however i am a bit unsure on how to handle so it only saves the actual difference between 1&2 - to a third text file.

See it as a "compare & save"

Hope someone have any ideas on how to achieve this, its a bit hard to explain.

---

**// Update**

Code snippet (Or look below): [https://jsfiddle.net/menix/py3eqnfL/](https://jsfiddle.net/menix/py3eqnfL/3/)

```
const ServerLog = "ServerDM/TheIsle/Saved/Logs/TheIsle.log";
const LocalSaveOld = "TheIsleData/TheIsle.log";
const LocalSaveNew = "TheIsleData/TheIsleNew.log";

async function example() {
    const client = new ftp.Client();
    client.ftp.verbose = true;

    try {
        await client.access({
            host: config.ftpHost,
            port: config.ftpPort,
            user: config.ftpUser,
            password: config.ftpPassword,
            secure: config.ftpSecure,
        });
        await client.downloadTo(LocalSaveOld, ServerLog);

        if (fs.existsSync(LocalSaveOld)) {
            fs.readFile(LocalSaveOld, function (err, data1) {
                console.log(data1);
                fs.readFile(LocalSaveNew, function (err, data2) {
                    console.log(data2);
                    var difference = fileDiff.diffLines(data1, data2);
                    console.log(difference);
                });
            });

            await fs.rename(LocalSaveOld, LocalSaveNew, function (err) {
                console.log("old was copied to new");
                if (err) console.log("ERROR: " + err);
            });
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("FTP ERROR");
        client.close();
    }
}
```

---

***This the code i currently have played with, it most likely needs recode obviously.***

What my thoughts is first it downloads the **ServerLog** file through FTP to PC (It saves it as **LocalSaveOld** on pc) - then it should redownload ServerLog again after 5 minutes, save it as **LocalSaveNew**

Then i wanna compare the LocalSaveOld with the LocalSaveNew - and have the "new data" in the 5 minute period saved to a third file (*This is what i am really lost on*)

**I figured out how to download ServerLog from FTP, save it as LocalSaveOld.**

**I figured out how to rename the LocalSaveOld to LocalSaveNew**

- I need a way to "**redownload**" & "**compare**" it each **5 minutes** or so, for new data .. **And save it to a seperate text file or something; this bit is missing in the code** (Lets call this *NewLogData*)

[A Friend here has a working Python example; but obviously mine is done in Javascript - I wanna achieve same result](https://pyfiddle.io/fiddle/2d38695b-b259-4287-8a41-741564110a98/?i=true)

Comment: What did you do? You should post your code and tell us what goes wrong

Comment: @Lety updating thread

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/menix/7jued8np/ Think i am onto something with the download.

It saves and checks old and new file so far, now i just need a way to compare each file & save the differences to a new textfile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const string1 = fs.readFileSync(LocalSaveOld, { encoding: "utf8" });
const string2 = fs.readFileSync(LocalSaveNew, { encoding: "utf8" });
const diff = (diffMe, diffBy) => diffMe.split(diffBy).join("");
const finalString = diff(string2, string1);
fs.writeFile("./TheIsleData/diff.log", finalString, function (err) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    console.log("written");
```

**Was the answer to compare - and i have it fully working now!**

Comment: First able to do that tomorrow it says! ^^ 
Thanks for the heads up, didn't know that was possible.